# Exception during json to object conversion : Could not resolve 'json__TypeId__' in 'javaTypes'

Tags: json, jms, spring-jms

I am reading a queue with json message and in the listener I am trying to access the message as an object from that json. This is the converter used:

```
@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("BrokerTrade.class");
    return converter;
}
```

I am facing the below exception.

```
org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve 'json__TypeId__' in 'javaTypes'.
```

The following is the sample json, which I am adding to queue using jmsTemplate.

{
         "id":1,
         "tradeSourceId": "mytradeSourceId",
         "messageOriginCode": "CXE",
         "sequenceNumber": "1",
         "messageType" : "TRANSFER",
         "movementCode" : "1",
         "transferType" : "NORMAL",
         "updateType" : "No Update"
}

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
>converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("BrokerTrade.class");
```

This is supposed to be the name of a String property in the message that contains information about the type to convert to - either a fully qualified class name of a value to look up in the class mappings to determine the class name.

If the message doesn't contain type information, you have to subclass the converter and override `getJavaTypeForMessage` to return a Jackson `JavaType`...

```
/**
 * Determine a Jackson JavaType for the given JMS Message,
 * typically parsing a type id message property.
 * <p>The default implementation parses the configured type id property name
 * and consults the configured type id mapping. This can be overridden with
 * a different strategy, e.g. doing some heuristics based on message origin.
 * @param message the JMS Message to set the type id on
 * @throws JMSException if thrown by JMS methods
 * @see #setTypeIdOnMessage(Object, javax.jms.Message)
 * @see #setTypeIdPropertyName(String)
 * @see #setTypeIdMappings(java.util.Map)
 */
protected JavaType getJavaTypeForMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
...
}
```

You can usually do that using an objectMapper...

```
objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(BrokerTrade.class)
```